# Appending Separate outputs to one dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 pieces of output as shown below. They come from 4 separate functions. I would like to store them in one single dataframe.

```
print("Number of Genes-", number_of_genes)
print(donor.ix[[0],0])
print(test.sum(axis=1).argmax(), test.sum(axis=1).max())
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work well.

```
print(number_of_genes, donor.ix[[0],0],est.sum(axis=1).argmax(), test.sum(axis=1).max())
```

Appending it to a dataframe doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your help.
NB, Each of these are for the same input.

Comment: You probably need to show what the print output looks like

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating an empty DataFrame with your desired columns.

Assign variables to your data.

One way to append the row of new data is via a dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['n', 'd', 'max1', 'max2'])

n = number_of_genes
d = donor.ix[[0],0]
max1 = test.sum(axis=1).argmax()
max2 = test.sum(axis=1).max()

df.append({'n': n, 'd': d, 'max1': max1, 'max2': max2}, ignore_index=True)
```